# Как изменить структуру пункта меню WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, cms, веб-дизайн, интеграция

Здравствуйте! Я создал меню из заголовков записей WordPress. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно изменить HTML структуру пункта меню, чтобы потом через CSS можно было его оформить, например, чтобы текст в одном пункте был не одного цвета, а как на картинке, разного:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'=>'Меню ресторана',
                    'container'       => '',
                    'menu_class'      => '',
                    'menu_id'         => '',
                ) );
?>
```

Comment: `<span></span>`

Comment: Понимаю, но как этот <span></span> втулить туда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте такой код в functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'filter_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2 );
function filter_wp_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        $title = $items[ $key ]->title;
        $items[ $key ]->title = '<span>' . $title .'</span>';
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Он оборачивает каждый пункт меню в `<span></span>`, что бессмысленно само по себе, но является иллюстрацией доступа к пунктам меню. Дальше вы уже сами сможете модифицировать строку, где span, для ваших нужд.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только там есть такой нюанс что синий текст, который на русском, и серый текст,  который на английском, это как бы один пункт меню должен быть. Мне получается нужно один пункт раздробить на две части, с помощью span. Если создавать меню не через плагины, а стандартными способами WordPress, то там ты просто пишешь текст для пункта меню и все, а вот как сделать чтобы часть этого текста была одного цвета, а часть другого?)) Если без интеграции, то понятно, взял в span и все)  но нужно чтобы пользователь мог управлять этим меню

Comment: Условьтесь, что пользователь должен вставлять какой-нибудь символ между русским и английским текстом, например, `|`. А в коде разбивайте строку с пунктом меню на две и оборачивайте в два блока <span>